# Is it possible to remove protection from a GPT Protective Partion HDD without formatting it?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, gpt

I own a 14TB HDD and it’s currently half full. I’m trying to use it via a USB adapter, but it is impossible because everytime I try to use it that way, Windows says that it is a GPT Protective Partition.

But this doesn’t happen if I plug the HDD internally to the PC, letting me to use it normally and being able to access all the info it has (this happens with the same single PC).

What I want is to use the HDD externally, but I can’t reformat the HDD since I don’t own another means of storage to backup all the actual info this HDD has.

I can’t either migrate from GPT to MBR, because, strangely, Windows doesn’t read or support MBR patitions but GPT.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible to remove protection from a GPT Protective Partion HDD

First, to address the title: "GPT Protective Partition" doesn't protect the data from being accessed; it tries to protect the data from being *damaged by accident.* It's "protective" in the same sense as a fuse, not a lock, and in your case it's doing exactly what it's supposed to – the "protective" partition shows up because it was "tripped" by a bad USB adapter which lies to the OS.

So if you were to literally remove it, that wouldn't make your data any more visible than it is now – it would instead make the disk appear *empty,* most likely leading to accidentally reformatting the disk.

Most commonly the real problem is that your USB-SATA adapter lies to the OS about how large the disk's logical sectors are – it pretends that the disk has 4096-byte sectors while in reality it has 512-byte ones. Since partitions are defined in terms of sector count, not byte count, this results in all data appearing to be at wrong locations – e.g. what was originally at sector 4, is now somewhere in the middle of sector 0.

With such remapping, the OS can no longer find the GPT partition table at all (because what it thinks is "sector 1" now goes to a completely different location on the disk), so what you're seeing is actually the *MBR* partition table – whose only purpose is to act as a "fuse" and make sure the drive at least won't appear empty, if nothing else.

[image: Diagram of 512-byte vs 4096-byte sectors]

There's no good way to fix this on Windows except by finding another USB-SATA adapter, one which doesn't do sector remapping. (Or, of course, clean repartition and reformat<sup>1</sup>.)

<sup>1</sup> (The problem works both ways – if you repartitioned the disk while it's connected through such an adapter, it would work fine *with the adapter* but you'd again have the same problem whenever the disk was connected directly.)

In theory it might be possible to carefully craft a new partition table that refers to existing data by its "new" location (as long as they happen to be exactly aligned to the fake 4K sectors), but this is very manual. (And would be much easier to do on Linux.)

> I can’t either migrate from GPT to MBR, because, strangely, Windows doesn’t read or support MBR patitions but GPT.

It does; in fact a MBR partition is exactly what you're seeing here.

Usually MBR wouldn't *work* with such large disks; it has a limit of 2 TB when dealing with 512-byte sectors. (Most likely, this is exactly why your adapter does sector remapping – with 4K sectors, the MBR limit becomes 16 TB, just about enough for your disk.)

But even if it's possible to use MBR here, most likely it wouldn't really help any more than just fixing the GPT.

Comment: Just coming here to add that this automatic sector size remapping done by this kind of USB-SATA chipset found in many of these must have been one of the stupidest decision ever to be taken. Ok, it works if you ONLY connect the disc through this chipset, but once you swap it (to another chipset or direct SATA), it all goes haywire. And no, this wasn’t an intelligent thing to bring > 2TB to Windows XP. It’s always been a botch and those responsible for it should be thrown off a 100 storey building (or at least publicly tarred and feathered)